# Check a string in array

Tags: powershell

I am looking for how to check the string values in array values.

My array `[array]$a01` contains values like below

```
WQA-JK-KUC-I01-hjkl-192.178.10.128/27
WQA-JK-KUC-I01-hjkl-192.178.10.160/27
WQA-JK-KUC-P02-hjkl-192.178.9.64/27
WQA-JK-KUC-P02-hjkl-192.178.9.96/27
WQA-JK-KUC-P01-NCI-hjkl-192.178.9.224/27
WQA-JK-KUC-P01-NCI-hjkl-192.178.10.0/27
WQA-JK-KUC-I01-EAD-194.270.24.0/24
WQA-JK-KUC-I01-KAT-194.270.28.0/24
WQA-JK-KUC-I01-ETKK-194.270.32.0/24
WQA-JK-KUC-I01-hjkl-192.178.10.64/27
WQA-JK-KUC-I01-hjkl-192.178.10.96/27
WQA-JK-KUC-I01-hjkl-192.178.10.192/27
WQA-JK-KUC-P01-NCI-hjkl-192.178.9.160/27
WQA-JK-KUC-P01-NCI-hjkl-192.178.10.32/27
WQA-JK-KUC-P01-NCI-hjkl-192.178.9.192/27
WQA-JK-KUC-P01-NCI-EAD-199.198.168.0/23
WQA-JK-KUC-P01-NCI-KAT-199.198.176.0/23
WQA-JK-KUC-P01-NCI-ETKK-199.198.184.0/23
WQA-JK-KUC-P01-NCI-EAD-199.198.170.0/23
WQA-JK-KUC-P01-NCI-KAT-199.198.178.0/23
WQA-JK-KUC-P01-NCI-ETKK-199.198.186.0/23
WQA-JK-KUC-P01-KAT-194.270.168.0_23
```

and I have two variables

```
$v01 = 'abc-ekc-20-ghjkl-79-cis-4321-WQA-JK-KUC-P01-KAT-194.270.168.0_23'
$v02 = 'abc-ekc-20-ghjkl-79-cis-4321-WQA-JK-KUC-P01-NCI-hjkl-192.178.9.160/27'
```

I write the code

```
if (($v01 -in $a01) -and ($v02 -in $a01)) {
    Write-Host "It is part of the array"
} else {
    "Not in array"
}
```

Output is: "Not in array".

Comment: Please read about [formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)

Comment: The longer vars `$v01/$v02` simply can't be **in** `$a01`

Comment: Take a moment to read through the [editing help](//stackoverflow.com/editing-help) in the help center. Formatting on Stack Overflow is different than on other sites. The better your post looks, the easier it is for others to read and understand it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To check only the part starting with WQA first split the content with a [zerolength look ahead assertion](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)

The `-and` operator needs the leading dash.

```
if ((($v01 -split '(?=WQA)')[-1] -in $a01) -and 
    (($v02 -split '(?=WQA)')[-1] -in $a01)) {
    Write-Host "It is part of the array"
} else {
    "Not in array"
}
```

Comment: An alternative without splitting would be to check if any one of the array elements `$a01` is in the vars `$v01/$v02`